# cant access node attributes

Tags: python, attributes, nodes, networkx

g.nodes() seems to display the attributes, but otherwise I can't access them . What I'm doing wrong ?

```
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_node('a', attr_dict={'k1':5})

g.nodes(data=True)
 [('a', {'k1': 5})]

g['a']
{}

g['a'].keys()
 []

g['a']['k1']

  KeyError     Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-62-03c0859d74e1> in <module>()
 ----> 1 g['a']['k1']

 KeyError: 'k1'
```

ver :1.11

---

upgraded to ver:2.2

```
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node('b', attr_dict={'k1':5})

g['b']
AtlasView({})

g.nodes['b']
{'attr_dict': {'k1': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For networkx 2.1 or 2.2, you can access the data regarding a specific node you must use the graph's attribute nodes. E.g.

```
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_node('a', attr_dict={'k1':5})

g.nodes(data=True)

print(g.nodes['a'])
```

Comment: print g.nodes['a'];
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: nx.__version__
 '1.11'

Comment: Is it mandatory to use that version? Apparently it's very easy in newer versions

Comment: upgraded to new ver